# Where is the Eclipse in Android Programming?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I format my PC and i wanna download again de ADT Bundle Eclipse + Android SDK, but, i don't find it in Google Developers -> [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

What's happened to Eclipse ? Now we can use Android Studio to programming for Android ?
Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: I recommend you to use Android Studio / IntelliJ (with Android plugin)

Comment: `ADT` is no longer supported, *Android Studio* is the new official IDE for Android Development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [this part of the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

So, yes you should be using AS instead of Eclipse moving forward. It's not necessary at this time, but it would be a good idea.

But to answer the initial question, you can go [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-development-tools-eclipse) to install the plugin for Eclipse. Or follow [the link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) that [puddinman13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386856/puddinman13) mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456628/where-is-the-eclipse-in-android-programming/28456685?noredirect=1#comment45239964_28456685)

Comment: In the event you still in need of or hung up on Eclipse: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/